# How to find pattern matching and save to array with preg_match

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to search url in string and save them into an array.
 It seems to be easy but i can't find the way to do this. I think it might similar to use preg_replace?

```
$myarray = preg_replace(
"/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",
 null, $input)
```

For example my input string is

```
$input = "    
    blah blah blah https://www.google.com 
    blah blah blah https://www.yahoo.com
    blah blah blah http://stackoverflow.com"
```

Finally, the result should be the values of three links that matched in an array.

```
$myarray[0] = "https://www.google.com"
$myarray[1] = "https://www.yahoo.com"
$myarray[2] = "https://stackoverflow.com"
```

I hope you understand my wish and sorry if there is something you don't clear.

Comment: Your regex matches `www.||||`, not sure it's a valid url!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use preg_match instead of preg_replace

```
preg_match(
"/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",
 $input, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

**Update :**

preg_match will result only single match.

For matching all the occurrence use `preg_match_all`

Comment: Thanks, It worked but why we need to use `$matches[0]` not `$matches`?

Comment: in preg_match, if matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.
For details you can refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php